# Close/Reopen votes - rep threshold too low?

Tags: discussion, reputation, vote-to-close, vote-to-reopen

This [perfectly good](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6439579/225647) question was flagged as a *possible* duplicate of [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3088098/in-javascript-what-does-it-mean-when-there-is-a-logical-operator-in-a-variable-d).

IMHO it very clearly isn't - the OP identified a particular usage pattern and asked about it.

Yet it has already gained four 'close' votes and so is perilously close to getting closed, even though the question itself has 17 upvotes and my (accepted) answer has 23 and counting.

This suggests to me that those voting to close it are not applying due diligence.

Given just how many 3k+ rep users there now are (>5500), should perhaps that threshold be raised?

**EDIT** ok, it did get closed and re-opened again.  I wonder whether the exposure of the question here on meta contributed to the rapid reopening.  I expect it did, since the votes on the question also jumped after I posted this question.  [and no, I wasn't rep whoring, as I hit the rep cap today already].

However, since the closure revealed who had voted, and therefore their reps, we can see that they were 33k, 10k, 8k, 7k, and 5k of rep.   The 8k user was the one that posted the original (IMHO incorrect) close vote, but there's no way to revoke a close vote.

I don't know whether those numbers support my original assertion that the rep threshold may be too low.  I'm inclined to think they don't.

Comment: There are more than 5 3k+ users participating in that question in a fashion that seems to indicate enjoyment of it. I don't think it'll be too hard to reopen it. I'm aware you're still speaking on a general case, but I'm thinking that in this scenario, you can probably make for an easy case to reopen this if it does get that last vote.

Comment: @Grace I would certainly expect that we could reopen it, but I'm sure that closed questions end up losing attention. I'm just not convinced that I now trust 3k rep users to make that call as it has become far easier to "achieve" that than it used to be.

Comment: What has the number of upvotes on a question or its answers ever had to do with whether it's a duplicate or not?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When a post gets close flags, it becomes easier to make the decision to add your close vote if there is a doubt, because you have community consensus.  That is true for moderators also.  I agree that sometimes people pile on their close votes indiscriminately, but that's why we have reopen votes.

The larger problem is posts that should be closed are not getting enough close votes.  Raising the threshold would exacerbate this problem.  Posts getting unjustly closed are comparatively rare, and are easy to fix with reopen votes or a moderator flag.

Note that *questions must be nearly exact duplicates of each other to qualify as duplicates,* and I don't think that's the case here.

A certain amount of near-duplication is desirable, see: https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/dr-strangedupe-or-how-i-learned-to-stop-worrying-and-love-duplication/

Answer (score 5):

The argument that the new question is not a duplicate of the old one makes a fairly subtle distinction.

The new question is ill-worded if it was intended to be different, because the proposed duplicate answer the questions *"What does this means “||{}” in Javascript?"* (the title of the new question) and *"I have no idea what || {} means "* (from the body of the new question) just fine.

The earlier question **doesn't** answer the question *"Why do I see the conditional initialization pattern `Module = Module || {}` a lot?"* which many of the answers have addressed, and which is the basis of the claim that the question is not a duplicate.

In other words:

1. The close was good, and the duplicate was correctly identified.
2. Someone needs to "fix" the question so that the very good answers can be kept under a good---and non-duplicate---question.

Comment: fair point - my answer was based on him showing that he had _some_ idea (even though he declared otherwise) but that he didn't know _why_ that pattern is used.  I'll consider revising the question myself.

Comment: @Alnitak: when you see a question being closed that you think shouldn't be, your first impulse should always, ALWAYS be to edit it. It's so much easier to just fix problems than it is to try convincing others that they aren't serious...